# Proving $\frac{a}{b} >\frac{a+\epsilon}{b+\epsilon}$ if and only if $b<a$, for $\epsilon >0$, $a,b$ positive.

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-writing, fractions

The way I use to see that this is true is to take the derivative of the LHS w.r.t to $\epsilon$. This derivative is negative if $b<a$.

I am not sure how I can use this to prove the if and only if statement though, or even if this is a good approach.

Would it just be something like the following: For the forward direct -- $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{a+\epsilon}{b+\epsilon} \implies b<a$, -- would I just say that because the LHS of $\frac{a}{b} > \frac{a+\epsilon}{b+\epsilon}$ is the RHS when $\epsilon =0$, then this means that the RHS is decreasing in $\epsilon$.

The RHS being decreasing in $\epsilon$ then means that  $\frac{d}{d\epsilon} \left [\frac{a+\epsilon}{b+\epsilon}\right ] <0$ which requires $b<a$?

Using the notation of derivative feels more high powered than necessary though.

> So the question is what is a good method to prove the result in the question. And, if possible give some comment or example of how to prove one direction

Comment: You could consider $\frac{a}{b} - \frac{a+\epsilon }{b+\epsilon}$ (which you want to be $ > 0$), and combine the fractions.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I see, that works. Thank you.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ positive?

Comment: Note that for all $a,b,c,d>0$ it holds
$$\min\big\{\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\big\}\leq \frac{a+c}{b+d}\leq \max\big\{\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\big\}.$$
It doesn't bring you straight to the point, but is definitely related and might be useful in the future.

Comment: you do not need derivative for this kind of problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a+c}{b+c}-\dfrac{a}{b}
&=\dfrac{b(a+c)-a(b+c)}{b(b+c)}\\
&=\dfrac{c(b-a)}{b(b+c)}\\
\end{array}
$

The sign of the difference
depends on all the expressions
in this final fraction.

Answer (score 0):

For a= 3, b= -5, and epsilon= 6, the statement does not hold, so we simply cannot prove it. So I am assuming that a and b are positive too, unless you want to correct me and add some other information that you might have missed:[Basically a proof for the "if" statement and the "only if" statement separately. Please correct me if I'm wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9ODg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Note all quantities $a, b, \epsilon, a+\epsilon, b+\epsilon$ are positive, so we can multiply/divide by denominators and preserve the inequality:
$$\frac{a}{b} > \frac{a + \epsilon}{b+\epsilon} \iff a(b+\epsilon) > b(a+\epsilon) \iff ab + a \epsilon > ab + b\epsilon \iff a > b$$