# Proving $\frac mn > \frac ba$ in $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, assume $b > a$, prove $\dfrac mn > \dfrac ba$.
>
> [image]

I solved this problem as follow,

Let $CH = h$ we have $b^2 = h^2 + m^2$ and $a^2 = n^2 + h^2$. Proving $\dfrac mn> \dfrac 
ba$ is equivalent to prove $\dfrac {m^2}{n^2} > \dfrac{b^2}{a^2}$. So we should prove $\dfrac{m^2}{n^2} > \dfrac{m^2 + h^2}{n^2+h^2}$ which is not a hard task for example by using the methods provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172431/proving-fracab-fraca-epsilonb-epsilon-if-and-only-if-ba-for?noredirect=1).

I'm looking for other approaches to solve this problem especially with less algebraic manipulations and more geometry involved.

Comment: BTW I like to think about your "algebraic manipulations" as the mediant inequality: since $1=\dfrac {h^2}{h^2}< \dfrac{b^2}{a^2}$, then $1=\dfrac {h^2}{h^2}< \dfrac{b^2}{a^2} < \dfrac{b^2-h^2}{a^2-h^2}$. (And both $(b^2-h^2), (a^2-h^2) > 0$ here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent $\frac{m}{b} > \frac{n}{a}$. It means you can compare angles by the base, because these are their cosines. As measure of angle rises with length of opposite side and cosine is decreasing, so left angle is smaller than right one - $b>a$ so cosine is bigger of smaller angle. CBDO

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thpught it would be that simple.

Answer (score 2):

Using that $\alpha = \angle CAH$ and $\beta = \angle CBH$ are both acute (so the $\sin$ and $\cos$ of both angles are positive), that $\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}x = 1$, and all side lengths are positive, we get

$$a \lt b \;\to\; \frac{h}{b} \lt \frac{h}{a} \;\to\; \sin\alpha \lt \sin\beta \;\to\; \cos\alpha \gt \cos\beta \;\to\; \frac{m}{b} \gt \frac{n}{a} \;\to\; \frac{m}{n} \gt \frac{b}{a}$$